# Выпишите базис этой системы счисления

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада, системы-счисления, информатика

Как известно, запись числа в большинстве позиционных системах счисления
определяется базисом и набором цифр, которые могут использоваться в каждом из
разрядов (в некоторых системах счисления в каждом из разрядов используется свой набор
цифр). Рассмотрим двоично-десятичную систему, которая относится к классу смешанных
P-Q-ичных систем счисления. В этой системе счисления каждая цифра числа в десятичной
записи заменяется на ее двоичное представление в четырех разрядах (исключение
составляет старшая цифра, там можно оставлять только значащие двоичные цифры).
Например, 2019 нижний индекс 10 = 10 0000 0001 1001 нижний индекс 2-10 (здесь пробелы добавлены лишь для удобства).
Выпишите базис этой системы счисления (10 первых элементов базиса для натуральных
чисел и принцип его формирования для произвольных чисел, в том числе дробных). Ответ
обосновать.

Моя попытка решения:

10^n

Поскольку за главную взята именно десятичная система, цифры которой изображаются при помощи двоичной системы.

Comment: @Drakonoved нужно выписать базис этой системы счисления и обосновать ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну все верно - базис только вас просят выписать как

> 10 первых элементов базиса для натуральных чисел

так и пишите -

```
1 10 100 1000 10000 .... 1000000000
```

:)

Вы все верно обосновали.

Как именно записать базис - как

```
1 10 100
```

или в двоично-десятичной как

```
1      1 0000      1 0000 0000
```

это уже все равно :)

Comment: а как записать "и принцип его формирования для произвольных чисел, в том числе дробных"

Comment: Да так же = скажем, 3.1415 - `0011.0001 0100 0001 0101`